# Pandas join() works, but concat() fails

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform outer join of two dataframes with the same row index using Pandas 0.14.1.

The shape of `df1` is `456,1` and `df2` is `139,5`.

Most of the keys in `df2` are found in `df1`:

```
[in] print len(list(set(df2.index)-set(df1.index))) 
[out] 16
```

`join` works:

```
[in] df3=df1.join(df2,how='outer')
[in] df3.shape
[out] 473,6
```

`concat` fails:

```
[in] df3=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,join='outer')
[out] ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 473), indices imply (6, 472)
```

What may cause this?

Comment: "The shape of df1 is 456,1 and df2 is 139,5"
Do you mean 1,456 and 5,139?

Comment: No: 456 and 139 rows. Indeed, error message is confusing because it reports the transposed shapes.

Comment: Possible cause: one of the dataframes has a duplicate index value. Discovered that downstream from the successful `join`. This may cause `concat` to fail, though the error thrown isn't obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get this error if one of the indexes has duplicate values. For instance,

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,1)), index=list('AACDE'), 
                   columns=['foo'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,1)), index=list('CDEF'), 
                   columns=['bar'])
```

then

```
In [50]: df1.join(df2, how='outer')
Out[50]: 
        foo       bar
A  0.846814       NaN
A  0.638571       NaN
C  0.516051  0.573165
D  0.789398  0.095466
E  0.921592  0.970619
F       NaN  0.061434
```

but

```
In [51]: pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, join='outer')
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 6), indices imply (2, 5)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly: discovered that the index in one of the dataframes has a duplicate value (by a downstream error). Appreciate the response.